# Why doesn't any frame shown when run in linux?

Tags: java, swing, ubuntu, user-interface, jframe

I have the following code.When I run it on Windows the frame appears.But when I run on Linux nothing appears. I tried to place show() below the line contentPane.setLayout(null); inside the constructor.That showed the form.But no labels or buttons were inside.Please help:

```
    public class MainFrame extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane;
    Process p;
    String s;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    MainFrame frame = new MainFrame();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public MainFrame() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 549, 426);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(null);

        JLabel lblRam = new JLabel("RAM");
        lblRam.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 48));
        lblRam.setBounds(212, 0, 140, 77);
        contentPane.add(lblRam);

        final JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();
        textArea.setBounds(10, 88, 384, 215);
        contentPane.add(textArea);

        JButton btnRamInfo = new JButton("System Memory");
        btnRamInfo.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                textArea.setText("");
                repaint();

                 try{
                     p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cat /proc/meminfo");
                     BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                         new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
                     while ((s = br.readLine()) != null)
                         textArea.setText(s);
                     p.waitFor();
                     p.destroy();

                     }
                 catch(Exception e)
                 {

                 }
            }
        });
        btnRamInfo.setBounds(404, 139, 119, 34);
        contentPane.add(btnRamInfo);

         try{
             p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("free -ms 5");
             BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                 new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
             while ((s = br.readLine()) != null)
                 textArea.setText(s);
             p.waitFor();
             System.out.println ("exit: " + p.exitValue());
             p.destroy();
             }
         catch(Exception e)
         {

         }


         JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("Advanced");
         btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                textArea.setText("");
                repaint();
                 try{
                     p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("dmidecode –type memory");
                     BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                         new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
                     while ((s = br.readLine()) != null)
                         textArea.setText(s);
                     p.waitFor();
                     p.destroy();
                     }
                 catch(Exception e)
                 {

                 }
            }
         });
         btnNewButton.setBounds(404, 89, 119, 34);
         contentPane.add(btnNewButton);


    }
   }
```

Comment: Have you tried removing parts of the code one at a time? Looks like you could do that quite easily with this code.

Comment: `null` layout is the first alert, `setBounds` of the frame is the second. Try using `setLocationRelativeTo(null)` instead

Comment: Every time you write an empty catch block, a baby bunny dies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could be because of this part of the code that is between the 2 buttons.Try removing it and see:

```
  try{
     p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("free -ms 5");
     BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
         new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
     while ((s = br.readLine()) != null)
         textArea.setText(s);
     p.waitFor();
     System.out.println ("exit: " + p.exitValue());
     p.destroy();
     }
 catch(Exception e)
 {

 }
```